# RegGetValue for value that may be either REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to get the data for a value that is normally of type REG_SZ but I also want to support the possibility that it is REG_EXPAND_SZ.

I tried this:

```
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkey, valueName, RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ, NULL, buffer, &bufferSize)
```

but it returns 87 ("Incorrect parameter").

It works fine if I pass either `RRF_RT_REG_SZ` or `RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ` on its own, but not when I specify both. I don't want to restrict my check to one specific type. The MSDN says I can use "one or more of the following" for that parameter.

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is there a doc bug? The [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly says that it is allowed to combine the type flags at will.

Comment: win10 noerror,  win7 really 87 error

Comment: Thanks, I'm experiencing this problem on Windows 7.

Comment: also the same - https://marc.info/?l=wine-patches&m=121632420706591&w=2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is a Windows 7 bug. In Windows 7 and earlier versions, the implementation of the `RegGetValue` function contains the following code:

```
if (((dwFlags & RRF_RT_ANY) != RRF_RT_ANY) && 
    (dwFlags & RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ) && 
    !(dwFlags & RRF_NOEXPAND))
{
  return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
}
```

Therefore, even using only the `RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ` flag will produce the "invalid parameter" error (error code 87).

This bug has been fixed starting from Windows 8.1. On both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, I have confirmed that `RRF_RT_REG_SZ|RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ` works without errors.

---

If you need to target Windows 7 and earlier versions, you can work around the problem by adding the `RRF_NOEXPAND` flag. In other words, if you pass the following combination of flags:

`RRF_RT_REG_SZ|RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ|RRF_NOEXPAND`

Of course, this means that values of type "expand_sz" will not be expanded for you—to do that, you need to follow up with a direct call to `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`. Also, you will need to use the *dwType* parameter to determine exactly which type of data you have, since you allowed more than one type in the mask.